# Передача обновленного в javascript параметра в форме post

Tags: javascript, html, post, get

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Делаю интернет магазин. Сейчас на этапе корзины. Ниже функция javascript которая меняет на экране началальную сумму заказа в зависимости от выбранного количества.
Каким образом передать через форму post новое значение ?  Не знаю как словить этот параметр.

```
var total = subtotal

/* Update totals display */
$('.totals-value').fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {

  $('#cart-total').html(total.toFixed(2));
  if (total == 0) {
    $('.checkout').fadeOut(fadeTime);
  } else {
    $('.checkout').fadeIn(fadeTime);
  }
  $('.totals-value').fadeIn(fadeTime);
});
```

Код html :

```
<div class="totals">
  <div class="totals-item totals-item-total">
    <label>Grand Total</label>

    <div class="totals-value" id="cart-total"> 100 </div>

  </div>
</div>

<form method="post" action="transactionSuccessful">
  <input type="submit" class="checkout" value="Checkout">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свой вопрос с помощью передачи обновленного значения сразу в инпут формы.

```
document.getElementById("input_total").value = total.toString();






 <form method="POST" action="transactionSuccessful" >

        <input type="text" class="hidden" id="input_total" name="total" value="{{ sum }}">
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" class="checkout" value="Checkout">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Дак вы же когда меняете значение, оно ведь хранится в html уже. Считайте его с помощью js и отправьте форму аяксом к примеру. Как вариант.